# past participle + conditional

Tags: verb, subjunctive, tense

Just finished reading the following article: https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/asien/hamas-fuehrer-israel-hisbollah-102.html

At one point, John Kirby, der Sprecher des Weißen Hauses, is quoted as having said: "Wir haben nicht gesehen, dass die Hisbollah der Hamas zur Seite gesprungen wäre."

What does that mean exactly? Given the context, it is kind of clear, but I'm puzzled by the last part, "gesprungen wäre".

Comment: https://m.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/zur%20Seite%20springen.html

Comment: It is not quite clear whether your question is about grammar or about what *springen* means in this context. The latter is answered by Olafant's comment.

Comment: The entire phrase is "zur Seite springen", which seems to be an idiomatic phrase not necessarily covered in a dictionary. Perhaps another cause of confusion is the use of the subjunctive here. Translated into English: "We have not seen that Hisbollah would have jumped to the defense of Hamas". This sounds odd in English, but maybe it makes more sense in German.

Answer (score 1):

This is Perfekt, Konjunktiv 2. The Konjunktiv is used here to describe something that didn't happen. This is to make clear that "we didn't see that X happened" here doesn't mean "X happened, but we didn't see it", but rather "X didn't happen" (or, depending on context, "we assume that X didn't happen, because we didn't see it").

Answer (score 1):

The relevant phrase is

- *jemandem zur Seite springen — to support someone*

The picture is quite literal. Someone fights, and you support them by jumping by their side, fighting the same opponent as they do.

---

If this is about the grammar, they use *wäre* instead of *ist* because it's a non-fact. Those are commonly marked with *Konjunktiv II* forms. *Springen* is one of the verbs that builds its Perfekt with *sein*. So the Konjunktiv II Perfekt is *gesprungen wäre*.

There are no separate conditional forms in German. Forget that term. Compare Konjunktiv II Futur I/II forms with the plain Konjunktiv II forms:

> sie spränge — Konjunktiv II — non-past non-facts
>
> sie würde springen — Konjunktiv II Futur I — non-past non-facts
>
> sie wäre gesprungen — Konjunktiv II Perfekt — past non-facts
>
> sie würde gesprungen sein — Konjunktiv II Futur II — past non-facts

In Konjunktiv II, the Futur I/II forms mean exactly the same as the plain/Perfekt forms.